# How to make multiple copies of one GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have defined/created one Gridview in my asp.net page.

Now I want multiple gridviews (it can be more than 10 also) in my page at run time.

How do I make exact copies of the of the same gridview?
By copy I mean, column widths, alternate row color, column header styles, data column name, wrap etc.

(actual data I am binding at run time). 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using asp repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CustomInfoRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>



    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Hi HeisenBerg, could you be a bit more detailed?

Comment: the repeater control can be used to repeat a list of items. Here, I assume you want the grid to be repeated. So give the the asp tags for grid inside the <itemtemplate>. Also like grid, the items has to be binded, like from a datasource.

Comment: Hi HeisenBerg, I have tried it, it is not what I want. I want separate grids for each set of data, and also separate header. sorry, wrong answer.